# how to export to static website using nextjs and sass?

Tags: sass, webpack-4, next.js

I recently started learning nextjs/react and got stuck following the tutorials on the official [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/static-html-export) website when trying to export my app into a static site:

I'm using sass for styling the app, and when trying to run the `npm run build` script, it throws me an error saying

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I've checked through my code structure & setup and couldn't figure out what went wrong. It looks like the error has something to do with the sass loader? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

below are a few screenshots of my setup.

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `sass-loader` dependency.

```
npm i -D sass-loader
```

and then add it like this:

```
config.module.rules.push(
  {
    test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'raw-loader',
      { loader: 'sass-loader' },
    ],
  },
);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I managed to fix the problem, but I'm still having two other issues after exporting all the files. 1. I have a duplicated header component. 2. css is not applied to all pages. Not sure what exactly went wrong here.

Comment: hmm, it seems you have some architecture issue. Is it possible to provide an example of your app?

Answer (score 1):

You have two `module.exports` in your `next.config.js` which is invalid.

Perhaps try passing the config to `withSass` and exporting that...

```
module.exports = withSass({ exportPathMap: /* ... etc ... */ })
```